# Validate only if the field is entered in Laravel 5.2

Tags: validation, laravel-5

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            'num_of_devices' => 'integer'
        ];
}
```

I want to validate an integer field if and only if the field is entered. But above rule validates it for integer even if the field is empty. I used `somtimes`, but no result. But when I `var_dump($num_of_devices)` it is string.I am using Laravel 5.2. I think It was working fine in 5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a rule to array, if input is not empty. You could collect all your validation rules to $rules array and then return the array.

```
if( !empty(Input::get('num_of_devices')) ){
  $rules['num_of_devices'] = 'integer';
}
```

Comment: Why do all this when you can just use `nullable`?

Comment: Close, but no cigar. The question was about Laravel 5.2 and nullable validation rule was introduced in Laravel 5.3.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh I see.

Answer (score 24):

From version `5.3` you can use **nullable**

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            'num_of_devices' => 'nullable | integer'
        ];
}
```

Comment: I just love this framework. Every time I think about something there is some solution out they for me. Thanks a bunch for this.

Comment: _Note_: The `nullable` validation rule is only available from `v5.3`

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for the [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) validation rule. From the documentation:

> …run validation checks against a field **only** if that field is present in the input array.

Comment: It was working (without `sometimes`) in Laravel version 5.1. But after upgrading to 5.2 it is not ...

Comment: ```sometimes``` only check if key exists on input array, not if the value is empty/0/null.